# Stock statistics calculation with O(1) time and space complexity

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I have to design a rest API in Java which :-

1. Accepts a POST request with the below `json` :-

   {
   "instrument": "ABC",
   "price": "200.90",
   "timestamp" : "2018-09-25T12:00:00"
   }

these records would be saved in an in memory collection and not any kind of database.

2. There would be a GET API which returns the statistics of the specific instrument records received in the last 60 seconds. The GET request would be :- /statistics/{instrumentName} Ex :- /statistics/ABC . The response looks as mentioned below :-

   {
   "count" : "3"
   "min" : "100.00"
   "max" : "200.00"
   "sum" : "450.00"
   "avg" : "150.00"
   }
3. There would be another GET request /statistics which returns the statistics of all the instruments that was received in the last 60 seconds ( Not specific to particular instrument like #2 )

What makes this algorithm complex to implement is that the GET call should be executed - O(1) time and space complexity.

The approach which I have thought for 3# is to have a collection which will have 60 buckets ( since we have to calculate for past 60 secs so sampling per 1 sec). Every time the transaction comes in it will go to specific bucket depending on the key i.e. hour-min-sec ( it would be a map with this key and the statistics for that sec ) .

But what I am not able to understand is how to address the problem 2# where we have to get the statistics of specific instrument /statistics/ABC for last 60 sec in O(1) time and space complexity.

What could be the best strategy to clean up records which are older than 60 secs?

Any help with the algorithm will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you require `get` to be always O(1) or is amortised O(1) acceptable?

Comment: @rici The get call 3# needs to be strictly O(1) time and space complexity both. And the get call 2# should be strictly O(1) in time complexity. This requirement actually drives the whole design of the solution.

Comment: yes, that definitely makes it trickier. Amortised O(1) is much easier (and usually acceptable in practice.)

Comment: When you say O(1) here, do you mean “needs to be fast in practice” or “this is a homework assignment and the requirement specifically is to hit O(1) performance?”

Comment: @templatetypedef : O(1) time complexity and space complexity for GET call i.e. /statistics/ means that the number of iterations for calculating the statistics as mentioned above i.e. average , count , min , max etc should be constant and not dependent on the number of records / transactions that we have received.

Comment: Would you be okay with something logarithmic? You’d need truly astronomical numbers of items for the number of iterations to get large in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Store the data in a `Map<String, Instrument>`, and have the class look like this:

```java
class Instrument {
    private String name;
    private SortedMap<LocalDateTime, BigDecimal> prices;
    private BigDecimal minPrice;
    private BigDecimal maxPrice;
    private BigDecimal sumPrice;

    // Internal helper method
    private void cleanup() {
        LocalDateTime expireTime = LocalDateTime.now().minusSeconds(60);
        Map<LocalDateTime, BigDecimal> expiredPrices = this.prices.headMap(expireTime);
        for (BigDecimal expiredPrice : expiredPrices.values()) {
            if (this.minPrice.compareTo(expiredPrice) == 0)
                this.minPrice = null;
            if (this.maxPrice.compareTo(expiredPrice) == 0)
                this.maxPrice = null;
            this.sumPrice = this.sumPrice.subtract(expiredPrice);
        }
        expiredPrices.clear(); // Removes expired prices from this.prices
        if (this.minPrice == null && ! this.prices.isEmpty())
            this.minPrice = this.prices.values().stream().min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();
        if (this.maxPrice == null && ! this.prices.isEmpty())
            this.maxPrice = this.prices.values().stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();
    }

    // other code
}
```

All the public methods of `Instrument` must be `synchronized` and must start with a call to `cleanup()`, since time has elapsed since any previous call. The `addPrice(LocalDateTime, BigDecimal)` method must of course update the 3 statistics fields.

To ensure statistics are in sync, it would be appropriate to have a `Statistics` class that can be used as return value, so all 4 main statistics values (incl. `count` obtained from `this.prices.size()`) represent the same set of prices.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But how would the GET call look like such that it will be o(1) in time and space complexity? Also how can we implement #2 since we have to maintain the name of instrument or some identifier in order to get the stats on the basis of instrument name. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If we call the cleanup method while a GET call then wont the time complexity be O(n) where n is the no of records of expiredPrices?

Comment: @CodeMaster Before asking a question about complexity, you need to establish what `n` is. For your question, `n` would be the *total* number of prices. Since the cleanup method is unrelated to total the number of prices, the amortized complexity is _O(1)_, similar to how the amortized complexity of `ArrayList.add()` is _O(1)_ even though it *sometimes* needs to expand the backing array.

Comment: @CodeMaster As for the first comment, regarding #2, please read the first line of the answer. What do you think the key of that map is?